# React: add route with mandatory query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm working on a project that uses Rails and React, with react-router version 4.2.0 and react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.9. It's the first time I use React and I'm having trouble routing.

In my routes.jsx file I have the following path:

```
const routes = [
  { path: /\/events\/(\d)$/, action: () => <EventForm /> },
];
```

When I type `http://localhost:3000/events/2` in my browser I get the content back.

I want to modify my route so this link won't be valid unless there's a `userToken` appended to it as a query string. (I know this is not the best security practice but it's valid for the purpose of this project)

For example, the following link `http://localhost:3000/events/2` should not work, but the link `http://localhost:3000/events/2?userToken=abc` should work.

I tried these options but it didn't work:

```
{ path: /\/events\/(\d)\?userToken\=(\w)$/, action: () => <EventForm /> }

{ path: /\/events\/(\d)\?userToken=[\w]$/, action: () => <EventForm /> }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check url param in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of `EventForm`:

```
class EventForm extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const {location, history} = this.props // these are by design in props when using react-router
        if(!location.query.userToken){
             history.push('/login') // or whatever route
        }

    }
    render(){
        return (<div>...</div>)
    }
}

export default EventForm
```